# $f_1(x) = \sqrt x$ and $f_{n+1}(x) = \sqrt {x + f_n(x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, uniform-convergence

For $x ≥ 0$, define $f_1(x) = \sqrt x$ and $f_{n+1}(x) = \sqrt {x + f_n(x)}$.

Prove that

$(a)$ $f_n(0) = 0$ and $0 < f_n(x) < f_{n+1}(x) < 1 + x$ for all $n$ and when $x > 0$.

$(b)$ $f_n $ converges uniformly on any closed interval $[a, b]$ such that $0 < a < b$, but not on $[0,1]$.

I have proved part $(a)$ but unable to do part $(b)$ .

I think that the sequence $f_n$ converges to $1+b$  on any closed interval $[a, b]$.

Comment: For $(b)$, if the convergence is uniform, then the pointwise limit $f_\infty(x) \stackrel{def}{=} \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$ will be a continuous function but $f_\infty(0) = 0$ while $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} f_\infty(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2} = 1$.

Comment: here I think we have to apply dini's theorem

Comment: You cannot apply dini's theorem over the whole $[0,1]$,  the limit function $f_\infty$ is not continuous at $0$. However, you can apply it to $[a,b]$ ( when $a > 0$) to deduce uniform convergence over $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Let $g(x,t)=\sqrt{x+t}$ for $x\geq0$ and $t\geq 0$.

let  $ x>0$ . By derivative,

$t \;\mapsto g(x,t) $ is increasing at $[0,+\infty)$,

and

$f_2(x)=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}>f_1(x)$

thus

$(f_n(x))_n$ is  increasing.

on the other, the positive fixed point
of $t\mapsto g(x,t)$ is

$$F(x)=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}>f_1(x)$$

So, by induction

$$(\forall n>0)  \;\;  0<f_n(x)\leq F(x)$$

$(f_n(x))_n$  is increasing bounded

$\implies$ it converges to the fixed point.

finally,

$\forall x>0 $

$\lim_{n\to+\infty}f_n(x)=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}=F(x)$.

and $F(0)=0$.

Observe that $F$ is discontinuous at $0$ and since all the $f_n$ are continuous at $ [0,1]$.(By induction),
$(f_n)_n$ doesn't converge uniformly at $[0,1]$.

Let us look at the convergence at $[a,b]$.

$(\forall x\in [a,b] )\;\; (\forall n\geq 1)$

$$|f_{n+1}(x)-F(x)|=$$

$$|g(f_n(x))-g(F(x))|$$

$$=\frac{|f_n(x)-F(x)|}{\sqrt{x+f_n(x)}+\sqrt{x+F(x)}}$$

$$\leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}|f_n(x)-F(x)|$$

$$\leq \frac{  1} { (2\sqrt{a })^n}|f_1(x)-F(x)|$$

$$\leq \frac{1}{(2\sqrt{a})^n}M$$

where

$$M=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}f_1(x)+\sup_{x\in[a,b]}F(x).$$

$\implies$

$$\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f_n(x)-F(x)|\leq\frac{M}{(2\sqrt{a})^n}.$$

As $a>1$, The convergence is uniform at$ [a,b]$.